# Ansible: can't access dictionary value - got error: 'dict object' has no attribute

Tags: dictionary, ansible

```
---
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - name: print phone details
      debug: msg="user {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
      with_dict: "{{ users }}"
  vars:
    users:
      alice: "Alice"
      telephone: 123
```

When I run this playbook, I am getting this error:

```
One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'
```

This one actually works just fine:

```
debug: msg="user {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value }}"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop over this dictionary in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167747/how-to-loop-over-this-dictionary-in-ansible)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not the exact same code. If you look carefully at the example, you'll see that under `users`, you have several dicts.

In your case, you have two dicts but with just one key (`alice`, or `telephone`) with respective values of "Alice", 123.

You'd rather do :

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: print phone details
      debug: msg="user {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
      with_dict: "{{ users }}"
  vars:
    users:
      alice:
        name: "Alice"
        telephone: 123
```

(note that I changed host to `localhost` so I can run it easily, and added `gather_facts: no` since it's not necessary here. YMMV.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to print `{{ item.value.name }}` but the name is not defined.

```
users:
  alice: "Alice"
  telephone: 123
```

should be replaced by

```
users:
  name: "Alice"
  telephone: 123
```

Then both the `name` and the `telephone` attribute are defined within the dict (users).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that with dict only works when giving the dict inline. Not when taking it from vars.

```yaml
- name: ssh config
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#?\s*{{item.key}}\s'
    line: '{{item.key}} {{item.value}}'
    state: present
  with_dict: 
    LoginGraceTime: "1m"
    PermitRootLogin: "yes"
    PubkeyAuthentication: "yes"
    PasswordAuthentication: "no"
    PermitEmptyPasswords: "no"
    IgnoreRhosts: "yes"
    Protocol: 2
```

If you want to take it from vars which can also be defined globally or on some other place, you can use lookup.

```yaml
- name: ssh config
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#?\s*{{item.key}}\s'
    line: '{{item.key}} {{item.value}}'
    state: present
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', sshd_config) }}"
  vars:
    sshd_config:
      LoginGraceTime: "1m"
      PermitRootLogin: "yes"
      PubkeyAuthentication: "yes"
      PasswordAuthentication: "no"
      PermitEmptyPasswords: "no"
      IgnoreRhosts: "yes"
      Protocol: 2
```

Answer (score -1):

small correction:

```
- name: print phone details
  debug: msg="user {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
  with_dict: "{{ users }}" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```