# ansible with_items with comma separated item.values

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create somehow a nested loop with comma separated item.values in Ansible. 
    vars:
    - my_resources
      - { name: 'share1', id: 'user1,user2,user3' }
      - { name: 'share2', id: 'user4' }

```
- name: Create users files
  copy:
  dest: "/etc/vsftpd_users/{{ item.id }}"
  content: |
    local_root=/vol/{{ item.name }}
  with_items: 
  - "{{ my_resources.split(',') }}"
```

My expectation should be as below, like every file gets created with appropriate contents inside.

```
$ cat user1
share1

$ cat user2
share1

$ cat user4
share2
```

However the files created like below with the above script

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22 Oct 11 08:15 [u'user1', u'user2', u'user3']
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29 Oct 11 08:15 [u'user4']
```

Is there any way of fixing this issue?

Comment: Refactor your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#) and [subelements lookup/query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/subelements.html), which is supported since version 2.5

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    users:
      - name: 'share1'
        id: "{{'user1,user2,user3'.split(',')}}"
      - name: 'share2'
        id: "{{'user4'.split(',')}}"

  tasks:
  - name: Create users file with content
    copy:
      dest: "/etc/vsftpd_users/{{ item.1 }}"
      content: |
        local_root=/vol/{{ item.0.name }}
    loop: "{{lookup('subelements', users, 'id', skip_missing=True)}}"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @Ignacio. Thanks a lot. please just update `loop` with `with_list` as per the link you have shared. Using `loop` getting error.

Comment: You're welcome! That could happen because your ansible version, loop is a new feature of version 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Ansible was not made to work with too complex data structure without scripting;
To made it easy you shall restruct your user data as a list of dict with single ids like:

```
- name: Create users file with content
  copy:
  dest: "/etc/vsftpd_users/{{ item.id }}"
  content: |
    local_root=/vol/{{ item.name }}
  with_items:
  - { name: 'share1', id: 'user1' }
  - { name: 'share1', id: 'user2' }
  - { name: 'share1', id: 'user3' }
  - { name: 'share2', id: 'user4' }
```

Comment: As per https://gist.github.com/angstwad/9893480 this should be possible. However now i am getting `'list object' has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: You will not be able to work with your data structure without using jina2 scripting. Ansible doesn't work with multiple activities per task. See an example here about dictionary iteraction:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167747/how-to-loop-over-this-dictionary-in-ansible