# Ansible Debug array of object for specific value using Loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, object, foreach, ansible

I have the following array of record with the value:

- myRecord.record.0.number = "Number 0"
- myRecord.record.1.number = "Number 1"
- myRecord.record.2.number = "Number 2"
- myRecord.record.3.number = "Number 3"

How to create a playbook to debug the above value using loop dynamically/for every array?

for other common languange it can be done as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myRecord.length(); i++)
{
   echo myRecord.record.[i].number
}
```

for the repeating task of the playbook, it will looks like this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  name: Array of Object
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: using debugMsg
      debug: 
        msg: 
          -   "{{ myRecord.record.0.number  }}"
          -   "{{ myRecord.record.1.number  }}"
          -   "{{ myRecord.record.2.number  }}"
          -   "{{ myRecord.record.3.number  }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this. Basically I just need to use loop_control to filter which specific value I need. Here is the playbook:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  name: Array of Object
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: using loop_control
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.number }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ myRecord.record }}"  #this will become 'item'
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.number }}" #filter to display the value of number only
```

Answer (score 0):

[There are two methods](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with). The first method uses the with_* keyword, and depends on the [Lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins). The second method uses loop keyword, which is equivalent to 'with_' + 'list lookup plugin' (so you get 'with_list').

Now, assuming your data structure looks like this:

```
---
# vars file for print_variable_from_list
myRecord:
  record:
    - number: "Number 0"
    - number: "Number 1"
    - number: "Number 2"
    - number: "Number 3"
```

Every number is indexable with the "number" key.

```
- name: loop through myRecord
  debug:
    msg: "{{  item.number  }}"
  loop: "{{ myRecord.record }}"
```

[Kindly refer to other posts for more complex queries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167747/how-to-loop-over-this-dictionary-in-ansible)

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. 

However, ur answer will display the whole value of the record. 

For example each record may have: 
- myRecord.record.[i].number
- myRecord.record.[i].name
- myRecord.record.[i].email
- myRecord.record.[i].status

What I want to do is that it will only display/list the 'myRecord.record.[i].number' for every existing records, not the whole things.

Comment: Hey, I edited my answer. Does it answer your question now?

Comment: I have tried that. It still debug/print the whole value of the records. What I did is filter the output by using loop_control as described above.