# ansible + how to to run import_playbook with condition

Tags: linux, ansible

is it possible to run `import_playbook` with condition?

here is example from my ansible code

we want to run `run_tasks_only_on_rhel8.yml` from `import_playbook`
when condition is only for rhel8 machines

```
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/run_tasks_only_on_rhel8.yml"
  when: ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "8"
```

but from ansible playbook output we see the following errors

```
 The conditional check 'ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "8"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "8"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'distribution_major_version'
```

what need to correct here ?

Comment: "_Is it possible to run import_playbook with condition?_", yes, of course. "_What need to correct here?_", just gather facts. Can you show us the debug output from `ansible_facts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check, if you disabled the facts in your playbook, as you could see below, this basic code works without issues:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: ansible_facts['distribution_major_version']
```

Answer (score -1):

According to another thread here: [Ansible: can't access dictionary value - got error: 'dict object' has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639325/ansible-cant-access-dictionary-value-got-error-dict-object-has-no-attribu)

It looks like the objects don't have the right var set to meet the conditional check, you might find the help you need in the thread I have linked.